# Split background 50/50

Tags: css, html, web

I'm trying to develop a landing page like that of http://www.lecrae.com. But I'm having difficulties, the picture page splits into two, but the picture doesn't show well. Is there anyway I can make the picture align with the page split and maintain it's full form? Please forgive my english. Here is my code:

```
              .rightHalf {
                           background: url(images/test1.jpg);
                           width: 50%;
                           position: absolute;
                           right: 0px;
                           height: 100%;
                        }
```

Thanks mates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply backgorund size and position

```
 .rightHalf {
     background-image: url(images/test1.jpg);
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width: 50%;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0px;
     height: 100%;
}
```